# Recording a video of Android app with a large presentable cursor?

Tags: android, linux, video, mobile, android-emulator

I'm trying to create a video of an app for a trailer where it is important for the viewer to see where is being pressed on the screen. What options do I have for doing this where a large nice looking cursor (in the sense of the one you see when controlling the emulator) can been seen?

I can record a video of the emulator which shows a small black cursor. This cursor is ugly looking and too small to see clearly though. Can this cursor be changed? The emulator appears to draw its own cursor and makes the system cursor vanish; I was hoping I could change the system cursor to be a large opaque circle that would cover up the emulator's cursor but I don't know how to stop the system cursor from disappearing. I'd prefer to do this in Linux but Windows is an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this cursor be changed?

Some screencast recorders can do that for you.

Comment: Any hints on what Linux ones do this? I've looked at the major ones and I can't see anything.

Comment: @jcdnton: Ummm... yeah, OK, not sure if any for Linux do. Sorry.